# HP Laptop Forcing Windows 10 Recovery Screen After Ubuntu Installation

Tags: 20.04, bios, boot-repair, usb-installation

I downloaded Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, wrote it onto a bootable USB, and installed it to replace Windows 10. The installation succeeded, but it will not boot the new OS. It instead takes me directly to the Windows 10 recovery blue screen (despite having wiped Windows 10 from my drive.) I've scoured the BIOS Manager and System Settings, allowed Legacy Boot, looked through EFI files, and can't come up with a reason why Ubuntu won't boot.

Since Windows 10 is gone, I don't have normal access to an operating system on my PC now, but I can boot Ubuntu directly from my USB. It just won't boot from the hard drive.

Does anyone have any ideas?

For reference, my PC is a HP Laptop 14-dq0011dx

Comment: how did you "wipe windows 10"? Did you leave a "recovery partition" somewhere? can you reinstall the entire OS and check off the option to use the entire drive to install Ubuntu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. I had to adjust the partition settings to default to Linux, as it was configured to attempt to boot Windows despite not having Windows installed any longer. Works like a dream now.